# Rmarkdown: Error reading bibliography file, unexpected end of input

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibtex, citations, pandoc-citeproc

I would like to render my rmarkdown file with APA 7ed citation, but I get this error when I try

[image]

Important note: I have over 100 citations in a bib file following this format:

[image]

Also, at the start of my rmarkdown file, I have the following code:

[image]

Please if you have any idea on how I can render my file with APA 7ed citation, I would be extremely grateful!

In the past, my code worked just fine with apa 6th edition from Zotero. However, now I cannot render my file neither with apa 7 nor with apa 6.

Comment: Does it run if you remove all the citations except for one? Based on the error there's probably a missing paren or end quote

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Now I just have to find where my error is. You are the best!